# Check date whether AM or PM in shell script and take action accordingly

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to check whether its AM or PM in a shell script. I have tried this:

```
if ( `date "+%p"` -eq "AM" ); then echo "Yes"; else "NO"; fi
```

But it shows:

> AM: command not found

Also tried = instead of -eq.

Comment: `if [[ $(date +"%P") == "am" ]]; then ...` Note: `man bash` and `man date` are your friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues in your current statement:

1) the format specifier `%p` in GNU `date` utility may contain lowercase of either `AM` or `PM` - depending on your current `locale`. It's better to use `%P` specifier as it contains lowercase presentation

2) In **bash**, `-eq` - is integer comparison operator, not for string comparison

The right way would be:

```
if [ `date +%P` = "am" ]; then echo 'Yes'; else echo 'No'; fi
```

---

To deal with any locale you may compare the current hour value (given by `%H`) with midday hour `12`:

```
if [ `date +%H` -lt 12 ]; then echo 'Yes'; else echo 'No'; fi
```

Comment: Thank You. Your answer has more clarity and it also gave immunity against lowercase and uppercase. So accepting this.

Comment: The locale can specify arbitrary strings to designate before-noon and after-noon. (For example, `fr_FR` doesn't provide anything, `hu_HU` uses `de` and `du`.) It would be better to use `%H` and check if the value is less than 12 or not.

Answer (score 3):

The locale can specify language- and/or country- specific strings to use in place of `am` and `pm`. For example:

```
$ LC_TIME=hu_HU date +%P
de
$ LC_TIME=fr_FR date +%P

$ LC_TIME=en_EN date +%P
pm
```

Instead, check the hour to see which half of the day would be used to provide a value for `%P`:

```
h=$(date +%H)
if (( h < 12 )); then
   echo YES  # am
else
   echo NO   # pm
fi
```

Or, force a known locale:

```
ampm=$(LC_TIME=C date +%P)
if [[ $ampm = am ]]; then
   ...
else
   ...
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

here

```
# String comparision with =
#  [ ] instead if ()
if [ `date "+%p"` = "AM" ]; then
        echo "Yes";
else
        echo "NO"; # Missed echo here
fi
```